# Additional icons with cordova config.xml

Tags: android, cordova, icons

I am using the local notifications plugin (Android) and I would like to add the notification-icons using the config.xml

For example I have a png file:

- ic_stat_music_play
- ic_stat_music_pause

As I need to add the files to the different drawable folders in the same way as I add the icons/splash, I would like to know if I can add the files using the config.xml

For example I add the icon for hdpi like this:

```
<icon src="assets/icon/android/drawable-hdpi/icon.png" density="hdpi" />
```

So far I tried:

```
<ic_stat_music_play src="assets/icon/android/drawable-hdpi/ic_stat_music_play.png" platform="android" density="hdpi" />

<ic_stat_black_call src="assets/icon/android/drawable-hdpi/ic_stat_music_play.png" platform="android" qualifier="hdpi" />

<gap:ic_stat_black_call src="assets/icon/android/drawable-hdpi/ic_stat_music_play.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="hdpi" />
```

But none works so far.

Any idea how this might work?

Comment: Right now cordova doesn't support adding other images, just the app icons. The plugin you use should provide a way to add the images, if it doesn't do this, open an issue on github as feature request

Comment: This can be done using Cordova hooks.  The official readme links a site with a similar example to what you are trying to achieve: http://devgirl.org/2013/11/12/three-hooks-your-cordovaphonegap-project-needs/